# Where can I ask for suggestions about making a web application?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

Which site can I go to for asking a *suggestion* about making an app or web application?

Of course, not **Stack Overflow**, because I already asked there and I knew it was not the right place.

Comment: This sounds like you are asking for ideas, or opinions, in an open-ended way. The Stack Exchange network is not really suitable for such questions; you might want to check out some other, more conversational forums.